# Restrict content on a content editor webpart

Tags: web-part, content

I created a content editor webpart, created a table and insert some links to documents on different libraries. Now I want to restrict the visibility of links based on the permission levels on the documents. eg. I have the following rows.
Document 1
Document 2
Document 3

If the user do not have read permissions on document 2 he should only see
Document 1
Document 3

How can I achieve it. To make things simpler I can create active directory groups and make documents available to only those groups. How can I and make the fields visible to only specific active directory groups?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to create three content editor web parts and audience target to achieve permissions.

Hard way is to use client object model to query permissions and display/show accordingly.

Comment: I wanted to do it in the first place. But there are too many documents and I cannot create webpart for each document. If I can use a code then I will reuse it for all the documents.

Comment: Create a custom visual webpart and use that. That will be much easier than using JavaScript.

Comment: I am not a developer and I do not know how to play with custom web parts. So I used this in the html code of the web part.
<div class="permissionEnabled" jquery1111013087359719202812="2" target-audience-users="mkrt\rkiran; mkrt\rjimmy"
I am able to hide the text for the rest of the users but the issue is the number of allowed users is dynamic and can change. I do not want to edit the code everytime someone is given permission to view the links. Is there a way that I can give sharepoint groups or AD groups insted of individual users ?